# Aframe Cursor disorted

Tags: camera, cursor, aframe, virtual-reality

when i enter the Vr-Mode on mobile you get an cursor to interact. Now my Problem the cursor is disorted. When i move the lenses of my vr-glasses i can get the cursor to be one but then my scene isn´t right anymore. Here my camera with my cursor:

```
  <!--------camera---------->    
<a-entity rotation="0 90 0">
  <a-camera user-height="0" wasd-controls-enabled="false" look-controls>
    <a-cursor id="curseid" visible="false" opacity="0" fuse="true" fusetimeout="4000"
      position="0 0 -0.1"
      raycaster="objects: .clickable"
      geometry="primitive: ring;
      radiusInner: 0.002;
      radiusOuter: 0.003"
      material="color: red; shader: flat">
      <a-animation attribute="scale"
                      to="3 3 3"
                      dur="2000"
                      begin="cursor-fusing"
                      fill="backwards"
                      easing="linear">
      </a-animation>
      <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" begin="fade" to="0"></a-animation>
      <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" begin="fade_cursor" dur="2000" from="0" to="1"></a-animation>
   </a-cursor>
    <a-entity id="redcircle" visible="false" position="0 0 -0.1" 
            geometry="primitive: ring;
            radiusInner: 0.007;
            radiusOuter: 0.0077"
            material="color: red; opacity: 0; shader: flat">
     <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" begin="fade" to="0"></a-animation>
    <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" begin="fade_circle" dur="2000" from="0" to="0.25"></a-animation></a-entity>
 </a-camera>  
</a-entity>
```

Comment: Can you provide phone model, browser used?

Comment: Does the problem manifest with the cursor example: https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/test/cursor/

Comment: im stupid i had my cursor on z: -0.1 this is way to close on the camera now everythings fine thx for recognizing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cursor is way to close on the camera i set it on z: -1 and now its fine